# using if with multible array values PHP

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have a string which will be added from the user

I will separate the string into an array
I'll separate each character alone

then I want to find a specific word which is

> if(

this is my code but I got an error

```
$StingFromTheUser = 'public class a
{
    if(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        //any thing
    }
} '//end of the string
```

I separate it using this code which is correct

```
$arr = str_split($StringFromTheUser);
```

Now I want to find if the code has if statement or not
so I'm going to search for the word

> if(

here is my code

```
for($i=0; $i<count($arr)-2; $i++)
{
    if(arr[$i]=='i' && arr[$i+1]=='f' && arr[$i+2]=='(')
    {
        echo $arr[$i].$arr[$i+1].$arr[$i+2];
    }
}
```

but unfortunately I got this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /fileName.php on line 331

Comment: `if` != `for`; if is not a loop!

Comment: I know (if) is not a loop, I used if to check if I got the word I'm searching for it which is "if("

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if($arr[$i]=='i' && $arr[$i+1]=='f' && $arr[$i+2]=='(')
```

Use $ infront of arr

Comment: That is unbelievable mistake !

Comment: Thanks and sorry for being so dumb :-D

Answer (score 0):

you forget `$` in your arr

it would be

```
if($arr[$i]=='i' && $arr[$i+1]=='f' && $arr[$i+2]=='(')
   {
      echo $arr[$i].$arr[$i+1].$arr[$i+2];
   }
```

and you use `if` in `for` condition:-

```
 for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        //any thing
    }
```